# Do I need a transit visa in Dubai International Airport (different terminals)?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, dxb

I'm an Indian passport holder. I have a booking from Bahrain to Dubai (return ticket) and a Dubai to India (return ticket). So I have to two different flights (Emirates & Spicejet).

Do I need a transit visa in Dubai International Airport if I have a layover in the airport, but I have to move from Terminal 1 to Terminal 3 to catch another flight?

Comment: Do you have a single booking?

Comment: i m an indian passport holder, i have a booking from Bahrain to Dubai (return ticket) and a Dubai to India (Return ticket). So i have to two different flights.

Comment: Yes, I will be having luggage

Comment: My flight lands at 20:00 in dubai and the next flight is at 12 Night.

Answer (score 3):

> I m an indian passport holder, I have a booking from Bahrain to Dubai
>   (return ticket) and a Dubai to India (Return ticket). So I have to two
>   different flights.

In this case you are not a transit passenger and you will need to show a visa for Dubai before being allowed to board in Bahrain.

Terminal 1 and Terminal 3 are connected. You can walk between the buildings easily. Terminal 2 is the odd building that is disconnected.

You only need a visa for transit through Dubai if:

1. You have two different flights, and need to collect your luggage.
2. Your flight is departing or arriving at Terminal 2 and the others are leaving from Terminal 1 or 3. In this case though, if you are a genuine transit passenger (there are very few flights that land or take off from Terminal 2 that are transiting with airlines that land in Terminal 1 or 3); you may be given an exception but in the majority of cases you have to land in Dubai, exit the terminal and then enter the other side of the airport at Terminal 1 or 3.
3. If your transit is more than 24 hours - in which case your airline will probably arrange a transit visa for you.

Comment: Thanks. Burhan. I have two different flights. (Emirates & Spicejet) and an indian passport holder.

Comment: Is your flight on Emirates only till Dubai? If so you'll need a visa for Dubai before they will let you board - and you are no longer a transit passenger (you are on a point-to-point journey).

Comment: i hve booked two flights - 1) Dubai-Bahrain Return 2)Dubai-India Return

Comment: "In this case you are not a transit passenger and you will need to show a visa" - Source?

Comment: You have two point-to-point tickets. One is on Emirates from Bahrain to Dubai - final destination Dubai. The other is a completely separate ticket with SpiceJet from Dubai to India. They are both return tickets, on two different airlines that have no code share agreement. When you go to check in at Bahrain, you will need to show a visa for Dubai since that's where Emirates is carrying you to.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=ae&SECTION=vi&SUBSECTION=is&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the database used by Airlines:

> Passengers can obtain a transit visa at Dubai (DXB) for a maximum of 96 hours. The passenger must:
>
> - transit for at least 8 hours; and
> - have onward ticket to a third country; and
> - have a passport valid for a minimum of 6 months from the
>     arrival date.

and

> E-visas can be obtained before departure at www.ednrd.ae .
>     Passengers must have a printed e-visa confirmation and airlines can check the validity of the e-visa on the same site by clicking on "Query GDRFA-D APP"

In other words, you can get a visa on arrival, **or** apply for an electronic entry permit [HERE](http://www.ednrd.ae). The second option would invariably get you through immigration quicker, because you need nothing other than your passport, entry permit and possibly onward flight confirmation.